# Where the DirectDraw initialization code is in the SDL2 code?

Tags: sdl, directdraw

Can you point its exact location to me? Should be somewhere in src/video/windows...

Or was it thrown out, and now GDI is used instead for software rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, not avaible anymore. In the first SDL it was in the src/video/windx5